# Cannot Set Value of JSON Data to Separate Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I wrote up the following script, which pulls all the data in just fine. But when I try to break it up into different cells, it returns nothing. What am I missing here?

```
function myMonitor() {
//GET KEY

var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(“NINFO”);
**var rowNum = sh.getRange(‘F6’).getValue(); **

//POST CALL

** var url = “http://monitor.incognito.org/pubkeystat/stat”; **
** var data = { “mpk”: rowNum**
** };**

** var options = {**
** ‘method’ : ‘post’,**
** ‘contentType’: ‘application/json’,**
** ‘payload’ : JSON.stringify(data)**
** };**

** var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);**
** var txt= response.getContentText();**
** var d=JSON.parse(txt);**

//RETURN RESULTS BACK TO GOOGLE SHEET

var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(“MONITOR”);

sh1.getRange(1, 1).setValue(d);
}
```

*Result:*

**{Role=PENDING, SyncState=SHARD SYNCING, Alert=true, CommitteeChain=2, NextEventMsg=12 to be COMMITEE, Status=ONLINE}**

Now if I try the same thing, and switch the last line to:

```
sh1.getRange(1, 1).setValue(d.Role);
sh1.getRange(1, 2).setValue(d.SyncState);
sh1.getRange(1, 3).setValue(d.Alert);
sh1.getRange(1, 4).setValue(d.CommitteeChain);
sh1.getRange(1, 5).setValue(d.NextEventMsg);
sh1.getRange(1, 6).setValue(d.Status);
```

It completes its execution but returns nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Put some debug like : Logger.log(d.Role) to check your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your sample data and it returned to separate cells as expected. But can you try this approach?

#### Code:

```
Object.keys(d).forEach(function (key, index){
  sh1.getRange(1, index + 1).setValue(d[key]);
});
```

#### Behavior:

- Iterates all the keys of object d and is placed in 1st row (1 value per cell which is similar to what your individual `setValue` in each cells do)

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

- The `d` value seems to be in an array. Try this one instead:

```
d.forEach(function (data, row){
  Logger.log(data);
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key, index){
    Logger.log(key)
    sh.getRange(row + 1, index + 1).setValue(data[key]);
  });
});
```

#### Note:

- Since I can't test the actual response on the fetch method, to simulate your data, I used:

  `var d = {Role:"PENDING", SyncState:"SHARD SYNCING", Alert:true, CommitteeChain:2, NextEventMsg:"12 to be COMMITEE", Status:"ONLINE"};`
- The above code should work if your `d` has value of:

  `{Role=PENDING, SyncState=SHARD SYNCING, Alert=true, CommitteeChain=2, NextEventMsg=12 to be COMMITEE, Status=ONLINE}`

#### EDIT2:

- Since your response is inside an array, you need to access it like `d[0]`
- Provided code below will also add a header, and will loop all results (if there were multiple data returned)

#### Code:

```
// header
sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, Object.keys(d[0]).length).setValues([Object.keys(d[0])]);
// contents
d.forEach(function (data, row){
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key, index){
    sh.getRange(row + 2, index + 1).setValue(data[key]);
  });
});
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: This returned the same results as I posted above for me. But, it is a much cleaner way to do it. The only way I have gotten the data to break out at all is if I use what you posted, but change "var d=response.getContentText();" This, however, just breaks it up by character. Would it be easier if I created a new sheet to share out?

Comment: Hi @JohnJackowiak, As I can't test the actual response on the fetch method, I used `var d = {Role:"PENDING", SyncState:"SHARD SYNCING", Alert:true, CommitteeChain:2, NextEventMsg:"12 to be COMMITEE", Status:"ONLINE"};` to test the data. Assuming your `d`'s value is equivalent to `{Role=PENDING, SyncState=SHARD SYNCING, Alert=true, CommitteeChain=2, NextEventMsg=12 to be COMMITEE, Status=ONLINE}`, the code above should work.

Comment: Hi @NaziA. I tested your way, and it did, in fact, execute correctly. However, I think I have found the problem.  When I used your version where the JSON data was in quotes, it worked fine. If the JSON does not have quotes, it does not. Since my original JSON does not have them, I believe this is the source of the problem. However, I dont know the solution to getting around that.

Comment: It just shows the quotes but that should be entirely the same when logging the data. I do believe that there is a problem with the actual data you are processing so unless I can also use that data, there's nothing I can do for now. Can you paste the `response.getContentText();` value in your post? Maybe that way I can simluate your data.

Comment: I will make a copy of the google sheet I'm using and post just the necessary data so you can see what is going on

Comment: That would be cool. but please do exclude confidential data. @JohnJackowiak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232927/discussion-between-nazia-and-john-jackowiak).